# How to create chronometer without view?

Tags: android, counter, chronometer

I need chronometer without view.
I tried with

```
chronometer = new Chronometer(getActivity());
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
chronometer.start();
```

If I try to fetch chronometer value from another button

```
Log.e("time",""+chronometer.getText());
```

it always gives 00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Chronometer` doesn't store the elapsed time and it calculates it every time it needs to update the display.

You will need to add this

```
Log.e("time",""+SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase());
```

to get the elapsed time.

To get the time formated as hh:mm:ss you can use this

```
millisec = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
Log.e("time",String.format("%02d min, %02d sec", 
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec),
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisec) - 
                 TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisec))
                           )
     );
```